# component.find() Not working when there is 1 element, but if they are multiple elements with same ID it works

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-components, find

I have a list of items that I am iterating. Each iteration generates a checkbox:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.roles_empty}" var="role" indexVar="idx">
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="{!role.Contact.Name}" name="{!role.Contact.Id}" aura:id="chx"/>
</aura:iteration>
......
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Do Call" name="do_api_call" onclick="{!c.reviewCall}" />
```

Controller:

```
reviewCall: function(component, event, helper) {  
    console.log(' - BTN CLICK');
    var options = component.find("chx");
    console.log(options);
    console.log(' - finish');

    // var result = [];
    // for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
    //     console.log(options[i].get('v.name'));
    //     if (options[i].get("v.checked")) {
    //         result.push(options[i].get('v.name'));
    //     }
    // }
    // if (result.length === 0) {
    //     component.find('notifLib').showNotice({
    //         "variant": "error",
    //         "header": "Please review!",
    //         "message": "At least 1 contact should be set."
    //     });
    // } else {
    //     alert('Selected: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    // }
},
```

If my list have 2 elements, I am able to work with options as they find the elements in the page that has that aura:id and easily I can check what is ticked (commented out section). However, when my list only has 1 element the component.find() doesn't work. Below what I have in my debug log.

I dont understand what I am possibly missing?

[image]

+++++++++++++++++++Salesforce lightning doc example:

Even following the example from

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation

Where:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="selection" type="String" default="None"/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select a color:</legend>
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Red"
            name="color1" value="red" aura:id="colors"/>
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Blue"
            name="color2" value="blue" aura:id="colors"/>
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Green"
            name="color3" value="green" aura:id="colors"/>
    </fieldset>
<lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.submitForm}"/>
<p>Checked items: {!v.selection}</p>
</aura:component>
```

And

```
({
    submitForm: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var options = cmp.find("colors");
        var result = [];
        for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].get("v.checked")) {
                result.push(options[i].get('v.value'));
            }
        }
        cmp.set('v.selection', result.join(', '));
    },
})
```

Doesnt work if you remove 2 of the checkbox, leaving something like

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="selection" type="String" default="None"/>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select a color:</legend>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Red"
        name="color1" value="red" aura:id="colors"/>
</fieldset>
<lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.submitForm}"/>
<p>Checked items: {!v.selection}</p>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reviewCall: function(component, event, helper) {  
    var roles_map = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.roles_map')));
    var roles_api = [];
    var options = component.find("chx");
    var result = [];
    if (options.length == undefined) {
        if (options.get("v.checked")) {
            result.push(options.get('v.name'));
        }
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            console.log(options[i].get('v.name'));
            if (options[i].get("v.checked")) {
                result.push(options[i].get('v.name'));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (result.length === 0) {
        component.find('notifLib').showNotice({
            "variant": "error",
            "header": "Please review!",
            "message": "At least 1 contact should be set."
        });
    } else {
        console.log(roles_map);
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            const e = result[i];
            roles_api.push(roles_map[e]);
        }
        helper.makeCall(component, event, helper, roles_api);
    }
},
```

Comment: `let options = component.find("chx"); if(!options) { options=[]; } else if(!$A.util.isArray(options)) { options = [options]; } let checkedValues = options.filter((option)=>options.get("v.checked")).map((option)=>option.get("v.name"));` is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

That's how [.find()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_component_find.htm) works, unfortunately. If there are no values, it returns undefined, if there is one element, it returns a SecureComponent (or SecureComponentRef for cross-namespace components), and if there are 2 or more, it returns an Array of SecureComponent (or SecureComponentRef). An appropriate check looks like this:

```
let options = component.find("chx");
if(!options) {
  options = [];
} else if(!$A.util.isArray(options)) {
  options = [options];
}
```

You may as well write a helper method for this (I did), because you'll be doing this a lot. Like every time you do dynamic iterations and want to find them later.

Comment: @manza the documentation example is written on purpose to have multiple items so it doesn't break. The link in this answer explains that you need to consider three possibilities: no values (undefined), one value (a SecureComponent or SecureComponentRef), and two or more values (an Array of SecureComponent or SecureComponentRef). Your screenshot on the left ("When one 1 element in the list") show the methods of a SecureComponent; it is not an Array, just a single component. This is documented, expected behavior.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you, I have posted my answer as I did it slightly different to your suggestion (someone might benefit). In regards your answer, "If there are no values, it returns undefined," I think that is not correct in the way that on the example that I made there was a checkbox, regardless of checked or not, that was probably part of my confusion, specially if I am dynamically generating them I dont have control if there will be 1 or if there will be multiple checkboxes generated.